# I cannot read post-data in my for-loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm have problems with post data using looping for, when I click the button it doesn't post the data it's said, the index not work properly

```
for($i=1; $i<=$jumlahpertemuan; $i++){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><input readonly type="hidden" name="pertemuan" value="<?php echo "Pertemuan ke-".$i; ?>" /><?php echo "Pertemuan ke-".$i; ?></td> 
        <td>
        <?php
        $querypresensi=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_presensipeserta WHERE id='".$i."'");
        $resultpresensi=mysql_fetch_array($querypresensi);
        if (!$resultpresensi){ 
        ?>  
            <input type="submit" name="hadir" value="hadir" onclick="" />
            <input type="submit" name="ijin" value="ijin" />
            <input type="submit" name="alfa" value="alfa" /></td>
            <td width="30%" align="center"><input type="text" name="tglpertemuan" value="<?php echo "date".$i?>"></td>
    </tr>
         <?php
        }
        else {
            echo $resultpresensi['Keterangan']; 
        ?>
        <td width="30%" align="center"><?php echo $resultpresensi['Date'];?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php
        }
}
```

Comment: when i click button the first index , it post index 5

Comment: Can you `var_dump($jumlahpertemuan);`?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here?

You have a MySQL query inside a loop which is really a **bad idea**.

Anyway, where is the rest of the code?? 
Where is `jumlahpertemuan` defined?
Where do you read the data you submit?